# Do the contragredient and twisted Jacquet functors commute?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a connected reductive group over a non-archimedean local field $F$, and let $U\subset G$ be a unipotent subgroup with a nontrivial character $\psi: U\to \mathbb{C}^\times$. Also, let $M\subset N_G(U)$ be (the connected component of) the stabilizer of $\psi$.

Let $(\pi, V)$ be an irreducible and smooth (hence, admissible) representation of $G$, where $V$ is a complex vector space.

With this setup, let $V_{U,\psi}$ stand for the twisted Jacquet module of $V$ with respect to $U$ and character $\psi$. This gives a smooth finitely generated representation of $M$. Also, let $(\pi^\vee, V^\vee)$ stand for the smooth dual of $\pi$.

Finally, set $\psi^\vee(u) = \psi(u^{-1})$.

With this set-up, one can quickly show that there is an injective morphism of $M$-representations
$$
\rho_V:\left(V_{U,\psi}\right)^\vee \to \left(V^\vee\right)_{U,\psi^\vee}.
$$

My question is whether this is an isomorphism?
This is perhaps an easy exercise, but I am not able to see how to conclude that the cokernel vanishes.

In fact, in trying to prove it, finite generation as a $U$-representation of the kernel of the Jacquet functor comes up, but that doesn't sound right at all...

Perhaps it is not true. However, as pointed out by @LSpice in the comments, notes of Casselman show that the result holds in the case the character is trivial.

My motivation is that the precise relationship between these functors arises in trying to relate two forms of ``local descent'' of representations.

Comment: For un-twisted Jacquet modules, the Casselman notes (specifically, p. 41 of http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf) prove that the contragredient of $V_U$ is $(V^\vee)_{\overline U}$ (the Jacquet module with respect to the *opposite* parabolic).  Thus, your proposed formulation probably requires some modification.

Comment: (Also, what does "though vanishing the representations are equivalent" mean?)

Comment: @LSpice, perhaps I am compounding my errors, but since the opposite parabolic is conjugate to my choice of parabolic, the corresponding Jacquet modules are isomorphic. I think Casselman leaves it as is because there is a canonical bilinear pairing when you use opposite Parabolics

Comment: I think that the same argument as in Casselman should provide a canonical lift from the twisted Jacquet module, hence a perfect pairing as before; just replace in (let's say, at a glance) Proposition 4.1.6 the conjugation of $N_1$ into $N_0$ by the conjugation into $N_0 \cap \ker \psi$.  (Of course I assume that you're choosing $\psi$ so that $\ker \psi$ is open; or maybe this is automatic—I forget.)

Comment: I was thinking something similar. The reference to Casselman is very helpful!